# How to manage eqFTP in Brackets to download files from server to pc

Tags: html, css, ftp, adobe-brackets

I am new to Brackets and I cannot find a solution to my problem.
I have a website and it has a CMS with lots of templates and css in different folders.

I need to modify all of them, one by one, changing styles, adding content and markups and so on. 
I just started using Brackets and just installed eqFTP in it following the guide and set everything.

Now how can I download, using eqFTP, all templates and css from the server to my folder project in my pc so I can modify them and upload them all from brackets?
For example: if my templates are in public_html/templates and css are in public_html/styles/ how can I tell to eqFTP to download them in folder project?

Answer (score 1):

dev here.
You should create new connection and then connect to your server, you'll see file tree and you want to right click on folder/file you need to download and choose 'Download'. For files you can actually use doubleclick which will download and open that file.
Hope this helps.